# D2L Passing ID/Keys in Header instead of Query Params?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is it possible to pass the the ID/keys as an auth header instead of the documented query params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time, no. Currently, the only supported mechanism for authentication with the Valence APIs is the IDKey Auth system passing signatures as query parameters.